# how to insert a picture using file chooser

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a program to register employees, and was wondering how to put a picture of the employees registered When do your record. I would use a button to select this file and attach the photo along with your registration? But how would this be done using JavaFX? Thank you!!

Comment: this might help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm

Comment: Okay, I'm still a noob in java, with very little
experience, so I apologize for any errors. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I managed as follows:

```
@FXML
private void searchPicture(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");

    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    if (file != null) {

        Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imagem.setImage(img);
        imagem.setFitWidth(171);
        imagem.setFitHeight(176);
        imagem.setPreserveRatio(false);

    }
}
```

}